# "Check render method of 'App' ". - Am I exporting incorrectly?

Tags: reactjs

I just opened this project back up after a while and I can't figure out whether I'm exporting something incorrectly or something.

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

console.log('React', React )
console.log('ReactDOM', ReactDOM )
console.log('App', App )

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I have 'export default App; in App.js but still complains
What am I not seeing here...?

Comment: Can you show the app file?

Comment: Can you provide the exact error you are getting? Also contents of App.js?

Comment: We would have to see the `render` method of `App.js` to help you diagnose an issue contained in the `render` method of `App`...